# how to make the dom elements center align inside the bootstrap panel in single row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to put two of my drop box inside the panel and center allign both of them in single line . But it aligns it in center in differen line. Could anyone help me, please?

```
 <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="RegionID">RegionID</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-10" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RegionID must be a number." data-val-required="The RegionID field is required." id="RegionID" name="RegionID"><option value="">Select Region</option>
<option value="1">Eastern Development Region</option>
<option value="3">Central</option>
</select>

                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RegionID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ZoneID">Zone</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ZoneID must be a number." data-val-required="The ZoneID field is required." id="ZoneID" name="ZoneID"></select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ZoneID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: @SabinKumarSharma can you show the how you want to display..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as i understand you want like this so please check and give the response about what you want

here you need to understand the grid system of the bootstrap how it works with the screen

and here it's reference link is given below

**[CSS Grid system Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**

here is the code you need to just include the **col-md-6** to the both separated select drop downs

```html
<div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="RegionID">RegionID</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-10" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RegionID must be a number." data-val-required="The RegionID field is required." id="RegionID" name="RegionID"><option value="">Select Region</option>
<option value="1">Eastern Development Region</option>
<option value="3">Central</option>
</select>

                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RegionID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ZoneID">Zone</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ZoneID must be a number." data-val-required="The ZoneID field is required." id="ZoneID" name="ZoneID"></select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ZoneID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the working of above code..

**[Check out](https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/1/)**

Comment: @SabinKumarSharma please check out the answer

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am trying to study the code and understand the Grid system of bootstrap.